# Hover on an image, change another image - with MULTIPLE first images

Tags: jquery, hover, jquery-hover

I'm trying to create a product selection table, where hovering on a colour shade changes the main product picture (to match the colour.)

The problem I'm having with existing scripts is that I can't get the setup to work for MULTIPLE first images affecting only ONE target image.

```
/* Teaser image swap function */
    $('img.swap').hover(function () {
        this.src = '/images/signup_big_hover.png';
    }, function () {
        this.src = '/images/signup_big.png';
    });
```

I found this script but not sure how to convert it to accept multiple images.

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Uc9ch/) for the current HTML I have. When one of the images in the table is hovered over, the picture below should change to correspond.

The live site is available [here](http://www.rubytuesdaycreative.co.uk/testsite/snood.html) if you want a better understanding of what I'm trying to create.

One part I'm keen on is to not have the images wrapped in a link, as this causes a nasty page jump when clicked (and they work in conjunction with a form so cannot be changed really.)

Comment: Somehow the Javascript seems to be missing from your fiddle...

Answer (score 0):

I actually have an even easier solution then:

For each image you want swapped out simply give them `data-hover` and voila :)

```
<img src="normalLocation.jpg" data-hover="newLocation.jpg" />
```

JS:

```
// this code will do the rest for you
$('img[data-hover]').hover(function () {
    $(this).attr('tmp', $(this).attr('src')).attr('src', $(this).attr('data-hover')).attr('data-hover', $(this).attr('tmp')).removeAttr('tmp');

}).each(function () {
    $('<img />').attr('src', $(this).attr('data-hover'));
});
```

Comment: Whereabouts should the data-imgLocation be declared? Can you help me out with any syntax for this? http://jsfiddle.net/Uc9ch/1/

Comment: Just added the HTML, you just create html5 data-attributes with your values

Comment: Quick question about this. The image swap part, how can I have two images? Should this be a link? I don't want the image hovered over to be the image displayed in the mainpic, it needs to be a different image http://jsfiddle.net/Uc9ch/4/

Comment: Oh so you mean just that each Image has a rollover, and when you get away from it, returns to the original?

Comment: Yep, if you look at the live site is may be a bit clearer. E.g when you hover over the 'red' colour option, it shows you a picture of a girl in the red scarf on the left. It then reverts back to the original set picture when you hover off. (On clicking the colour shade image, it changes the value of a drop-down menu which you can then click add to basket for)

Comment: Just updated it, code from my library, real easy to use :) Any image with `data-hover=""` will rollover on hover!

Comment: Would you be able to do this with a JS Fiddle? I am not understanding where the HTML should go. Is this the HTML for the table colour shade or the main pic?!

Comment: It's for each individual Image, you also need to have jQuery turned on, and have the code in the Document.ready. Here is the working code: If you open up the console log you'll see it's trying to change the image but of course that image doesn't exist http://jsfiddle.net/Uc9ch/6/